# Operation not permitted with node-sass install

Tags: node.js, node-sass, libsass

I currently want to install node-sass in a project but every time I get this error

**error: unable to rename temporary 'Release / obj.target / libsass / src / libsass / src / color_maps-5ff12a01.o.tmp' to output file 'Release / obj.target / libsass / src / libsass / src / color_maps.o ':' Operation not permitted '**
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [Release / obj.target / libsass / src / libsass / src / color_maps.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/{$HOME}/Workspace/bo/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js: 376: 20)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal / child_process.js: 277: 12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/{$HOME}/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node" "/Users/{$HOME}/Workspace/bo/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" " --verbose "" --libsass_ext = "" --libsass_cflags = "" --libsass_ldflags = "" --libsass_library = "
gyp ERR! cwd / Users / {$HOME} / Workspace / bo / node_modules / node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1

- My node version is: **v14.17.0**
- npm version: **6.14.13**
- node-sass version: "**^4.14.1**", (this is what i have in package.json)
- OS platform: **MACOS Monterey Chip M1**

Please someone would have an idea of ​​this error, I tried to clean the cache with `npm cache clean --force`, to reinstall the version of node with nvm but I still have the same error

Answer (score 1):

Give up `node-sass` and use `sass` instead. It is almost totally compatible (details here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) and it was the only thing that allowed me to resume work on my project after changing to a M1 computer.

> yarn remove node-sass

> yarn add sass

Related: Gulp-sass officially recommends to exchange those dependencies - https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/803